# Rotating image by very small angle, e.g. 0.5deg

Tags: graphics, rotating, includegraphics

Is there a way to rotate an image by a very small angle? I'm familiar with the "angle" option of \includegraphics[angle=...]{image.png}, but it seems that this only takes integer values, and does not work for 0.5 degree rotations, for instance.

Comment: `\includegraphics[angle=0.5]{example-image-duck}` works.

Comment: See my answer below with a rotated image. And yes, this differs from `angle=1` for me as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks for info. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this issue? I'm using "\usepackage[]{graphicx}" as well so I have no clue what could be causing this issue.

Comment: Could you post your log file for a minimal document where you don't see the rotation?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the problem but the first attempt at a MWE works, so the problem must be somewhere else in my document. Since this particular document is very large it'll take me a couple of hours to add all of the packages etc. one-by-one to figure out what exactly causes the issue. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `angle` option works with numbers <1 as well. Obviously the effect isn't easy to notice, but see the following:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[height=15cm]{example-image-duck-portrait}%
\includegraphics[height=15cm,angle=0.5]{example-image-duck-portrait}
\end{document}
```

[image]